# jquery view source of created elements

Tags: jquery

If one is using jquery to create elements, remove elements etc. how can one view the source/html that reflects the updated document structure. I have tried the usual "view source" but i don't see the new document structure.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, use Firebug.
In Chrome, use DevTools (Command+Option+C / Ctrl+Shift+C).

Comment: @srchulo well start using F12 **☻**

Comment: Here's the full list of shortcuts (DevTools) [https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

*Use chrome for example:*

Right click the element, then click **Inspect Element**.

Comment: If you want to save the updated document just copy the element as HTML (pick from context menu after rclick) and paste to the notepad.